# How to connect to another machine behind multiple gateways using IP?

Tags: sockets, tcp, ip, network-protocols

I did not know where to ask this so here it is. This is more of a networking technology question, but any pointers will help.

Suppose, I want to connect to a machine behind multiple gateways. Say I want to connect to my home computer from my office computer. My home computer is behind my ISP's gateway and then behind my wireless router at home. Let's say I know the IP's for all of them. (global IP for my ISP's gateway, local IP for my wireless router within my ISP's n/w and my home machine's local IP within my home). How do I initiate a TCP connection with my home computer ? The standard berkeley socket program only takes one IP and so I can only connect to machines that have global IPs.

Is there a solution ? Am I correct about the berkeley sockets ?

Thanks.

Comment: You need port forwarding. If your ISP IP is also NAT'd, that may not be possible.

Comment: hmmm. port forwarding. is that supposed to be supported by default in TCP ? I am assuming its a TCP layer thing.

Comment: I assume by gateway you mean something like a router, where a public IP interfaces to a private network and all the computers in that network use private IPs. In that case the router has to be configured to forward a port to the private IP, or only an outgoing connection can be established.

Comment: yes, that's what i mean. Is port forwarding also supported on the ISP's gateway ?

Comment: Most routers, gateways and modems I've worked with have a port forwarding feature. If you can get access to it, you can probably set it up.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by behind your ISP gateway in this question.  ISPs normally do not issue a private IP address to the external interface of your cable or dsl modem (also called CPE)... What is the external IP address of your CPE?  You don't have to disclose the last octet of the ip address... the first three are fine (such as 24.2.18.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible, **with the cooperation of the ISP**. The fact that the ISP is giving private addresses should urge you to move to another.

The concept you're after is called DNAT or [Port Forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

Let's say you decide on accessing port `1234` on a PC. The address of the PC is `Local2`. The address of the wireless router (in the network with the ISP) is `Local1`.

- The wireless router must do the translation `Local1:X -> Local2:1234`
- The ISP router must do the translation `Public:1234 -> Local1:X`

The `X` means any port can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to know the destination IP address to connect from an application, the gateway address is for the forwarding (routing) of packets which is handled by the OS network stack. However, if the destination is behind NAT, you'll only know the public IP address of the destination's NAT device. Even in this scenario, all you have would be an IP address and you don't really know if there is NAT going on.

If your destination is fixed, you could set up port forwarding on the NAT device (if you control it). Otherwise, you just realized that NAT is pure evil.

In your situation, it appears you want to connect to your home computer. If your wireless device has a public IP address, you can setup port forwarding on that to forward all **incoming** traffic on a port to a port on your home computer.